# System.StackOverflowException while calling ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline tweetsharp

Tags: asp.net, twitter, tweetsharp

I need to show the feeds in my twitter account in a website.

I created the application in twitter with all 4 parameters filled. 
Permission is read and write. Generated the keys, tokens etc.

From the nugget manager downloaded tweetsharp, added a reference to the library.

Using the below code I am trying to get the tweets, but getting 'System.StackOverflowException' while calling ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
           var service = new TwitterService();
            service.AuthenticateWith(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret);

            var tweets = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions());
}
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Any suggestions please.

Comment: This has happened due to the proxy issue. var service = new TwitterService(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret,proxy); can be used for this as per some samples. But i could'nt get it right so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try unofficial tweetsharp library.